# Designing a FSM in VHDL using 2 processes

Tags: vhdl, fsm

I tried to design a FSM using 2 processes though i have too many syntax errors.
I can't understand what is wrong .
The most of the errors are like this "syntax error near if/else" etc.

```
entity myFSM is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RST : in  STD_LOGIC;
           IN0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           IN1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           IN2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           LED : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end myFSM;

architecture Behavioral of myFSM is
        type state is (A, B, C);
        signal currentS, nextS: state;
myFSM_comb: process (currentS, IN0, IN1, IN2)
begin
    case currentS is
        when A =>   LED <= "11111111";
                        if IN0 = '1' then nextS<=B;
                        else if IN1 = '1' then nextS<=C;
                        else            nextS<=A;
                        end if;
        when B =>   LED <= "11000011";
                        if IN0 = '1' then nextS<=C;
                        else if IN1 = '1' then nextS<=A;
                        else nextS<=B;
                        end if;
        when C =>   LED <= "00111100";
                        if IN0 = '1' then nextS<=A;
                        else if IN1 = '1' then nextS<=B;
                        else nextS<=C;
                        end if;
    end case;
end process;

myFSM_synch: process(CLK,RST)
begin 
    if (RST='1')        then    currentS<=A;
    elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then; currentS<= nextS;
    end if;
end process ;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The keyword `else if` must be `elsif`. Btw. your FSM has no initial state. Please always post the exact error message and mark the source code line.

Comment: About elsif i changed it and still error occurs .

Comment: Oh, now I see it there is a missing `begin` before `myFSM_comb`.

Comment: oh thanks so much i would never find it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the following faults:

- The keyword for *else if* is `elsif`.
- There is a missing `begin` before the first process.
- The FSM has no initial state

  ```
  signal currentS : state := A;
  ```

This is a fixed and improved version of your code. It uses a default assignment for `nextS`.

```
myFSM_comb: process (currentS, IN0, IN1, IN2) -- IN2 is unused
begin
   nextS <= currentS;
   LED   <= "11111111";

  case currentS is
    when A =>
      LED <= "11111111";
      if IN0 = '1' then
        nextS<=B;
      elsif IN1 = '1' then
        nextS<=C;
      end if;
    when B =>
      LED <= "11000011";
      if IN0 = '1' then
        nextS<=C;
      elsif IN1 = '1' then
        nextS<=A;
      end if;
    when C =>
      LED <= "00111100";
      if IN0 = '1' then
        nextS<=A;
      elsif IN1 = '1' then
        nextS<=B;
      end if;
  end case;
end process;
```

Comment: This is not the complete error message, is it? You can edit your question to add new information. What tool do you use?